# gnutls configure error: checking for libgcrypt... no

Tags: linux, compilation, libgcrypt, vmime, gnutls

I configured and compiled libgpg-error and libgcrypt but could not install(make install) as i donot have the root permissions.
When I try to configure libgnutls, i get this error.

```
tactuser@eqhttd01:gnutls-2.10.0 >./configure --with-libgcrypt-prefix=/home/tactuser/Mail/vmime/TLS/libgcrypt-1.5.0/src/
    checking for libgcrypt... no 
    configure: error: 
    libgcrypt was not found. You may want to get it from ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgcrypt/
```

In the **config.log**, I find these errors:

```
configure:7781: checking for libgcrypt

configure:7803: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  -lgcrypt -lgpg-error >&5

conftest.c:27:20: error: gcrypt.h: No such file or directory

conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:31: error: variable 'i' has initializer but incomplete type

conftest.c:31: error: 'GCRY_CIPHER_CAMELLIA128' undeclared (first use in this function)

conftest.c:31: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

conftest.c:31: error: for each function it appears in.)

conftest.c:31: error: storage size of 'i' isn't known

configure:7803: $? = 1
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile and install libgcrypt, if doesn't work, try with a libgcrypt version that is compatible with gnutls 2.10.0 (released at same).

Comment: I compiled libgcrypt but donot have the root permissions to install.Its at the path /home/tactuser/Mail/vmime/TLS/libgcrypt , i gave the same while configuring gnutls along with the with-libgcrypt-prefix but still no luck.

Comment: Well, if you don't have permission to install in any permanent directory, intall in /tmp.